# pyenv not recognizing environment names

Tags: python, pyenv

Summary: To activate a pyenv environment, pyenv is requiring me to include the path to the environment instead of just the environment name.

I was previously able to run `pyenv activate env_name`, whereas now I must run `pyenv activate 3.9.1/envs/env_name`.

I accidentally deleted some files in my home directory, but I still had (at least some of) my .pyenv, and it still contained files in the `versions` directory with the names of my environments. When I ran `pyenv`, it did not recognize the command.

So I reinstalled pyenv, first copying the old .pyenv into a separate forlder, and then I copied the contents of `versions` and `shims` into the new .pyenv.

Now, if I run `pyenv versions` or `pyenv virtualenvs`, it does include the environment I want: `3.9.1/envs/env_name`. However, if I type `pyenv activate env_name`, it says that there is no virtual environment with that name. However, If I type `pyenv activate 3.9.1/envs/env_name`, it does work. In the past, before accidentally deleting those files, it would recognize my environment without prepending `3.9.1/envs` on the environment name.

I'm running linux.

Comment: Does `pyenv virtualenvs` also show `env_concept_context` by itself?

Comment: @9769953, no, it doesn't.

Comment: And if you create a new environment, are there two versions of this new environment? Or also just one.

Comment: I made a new environment, `test_env`, and this one *does* appear twice:

`pyenv virtualenvs` returns:

```
  3.9.1/envs/env_name (created from /home/jalvarez/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1)
  3.9.1/envs/test_env (created from /home/jalvarez/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1)
* test_env (created from /home/jalvarez/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1)
```

`pyenv versions` returns:

```
  system
  3.7.4
  3.9.1
  3.9.1/envs/env_name
  3.9.1/envs/test_env
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `pyenv` itself doesn't seem broken (it can create new versions with their alias (symbolic link) just fine), it's probably just the symbolic links that have disappeared.

From a quick test, it appears you can very simply recreate the virtual environment, and everything (packages installed) will still be there, while you get the alias again.

So try

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.9.1 env_name
```

It may complain, and ask to continue: just enter `y` (I think the `--force` option can also do it, in case you have many virtual environments to repair and want to do that in a loop or so).

Check after doing the first one, if `pyenv virtualenvs` now lists the full name and the alias, then continue with the others.

If you want to be safe, first make a backup of the first virtual environment you're testing this on, or save the installed packages into a list somewhere (`pip freeze > pip.list` or so), so it's easy to recover if something goes wrong. But as mentioned, my quick tests shows `pyenv virtualenv` just recreates the symbolic link, nothing really more, since the other parts of the virtual environment already exists (that is, creating a virtual environment doesn't remove an existing one).